# Is it possible to create a Pre-defined Range Filter Facet in ElasticSearch?

Tags: filter, elasticsearch, range, facet

I have a need to have a Predefined Range filter facet. The Range filter will be for a school's grade range. I want K-2, 3-5, 6-8, 9-12, Everyone. My records have MinGrade and MaxGrade fields. They can have values K, 1, 2... ,12 or Everyone.I figured I might use a range filter. But I could not figure out how to use 2 different fields combined, to fall into the predefined ranges above.
Any suggestions? I hope this makes sense.

I want the facet output to look like this....

- K-2 (xxx)
- 3-5 (xxx)
- 6-8 (xxx)
- 9-12 (xxx)
- Everyone else (xxx)

Since I changed to 1 DB column, I have the range query working, Also curious if it is possible to add a custom Label like below `"facets": {
                  "Grade": {
                      "range": {
                            "field": "Grade",
                            "ranges": [
                                {"label" : "K-2", "gte": 0, "lte": 2},
                                {"label" : "3-5", "gte": 3, "lte": 5},
                                {"label" : "6-8", "gte": 6, "lte": 8},
                                {"label" : "9-12", "gte": 9, "lte": 12},
                                {"label" : "Above 12", "gte": 13}
                            ]
                        }
                  }
           }`

Comment: Can you give an example in pseudo-code how a range filter would look with multiple fields. (`mingrade` and `maxgrade`)? I have a hard time picturing what you want to accomplish.

Comment: example record...  recordNo, title, minGrade, maxGrade .... example data... 2345, 'myVideo1', 1, 2 ... 5678, 'video2', 6, 8 .... 6789, 'video3', K,1  .... notice some videos fall into a range between K-2 & 6-8 etc. .... hope this helps

Comment: so you just want to set 2 separate range filters? 1 on `minGrade` and 1 on `maxGrade`?

Comment: I just edited my question with what I want the output filter to look like. I am debating on changing my query, so that the grades come back in one column, then I think it may be easier to make a range filter for one column, I would just need the correct syntax

Comment: ok, I understand the facet output. Normally I would think there would be a field `grade` per record? I don't understand what `minGrade` and `maxGrade` per record mean, and how they relate to your output. Can you for example describe in pseudo-logic (english) what records (in terms of `minGrade` and `maxGrade`) would fall in `3-5` ?

Comment: Yes, all records will have a Grade on it. In the database, a record is one to many for Grades. So a video record is appropriate for a minimum Grade of 1st grade and a Maximum of 2nd Grade. (So in theory, there are two records in the database, one for Grade 1, and one for grade 2) Like I said above, I changed my query to return all Grades in one column now, so each row will have a Grade on it. I just need the correct syntax, to make the above output filter appear. FYI, the values for Grades are ... 0-13

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comment back-and-forth I believe I understand what you want.

I.e.:
a record `A` may be shown for every grade between `minGrade`  and `maxGrade`.

For example: 
a record `123` may be shown for every grade between `minGrade = 2`  and `maxGrade = 6`.

Queries:

1. for a given grade x, return all records for which `minGrade <= x <= maxGrade`
2. **asked here I believe**: for a given range on grade, say `[x1. x2]`, determine all records that have a *non-empty overlap* given their range `[minGrade, maxGrade]`

as follows:

1. Given grade `x` (in pseudo code): `minGrade <= x AND x <= maxGrade`
2. You need to construct separate [filter-facets](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-facets-filter-facet.html) for each bucket. e.g.: for `6-8` you could do either 1 of the following:

   1. `(minGrade <= 6 AND 6 <= maxGrade) OR (minGrade <= 8 AND 8 <= maxGrade)`
   2. `(6 <= minGrade AND minGrade <= 8) OR (6 <= maxGrade AND maxGrade <= 8)`

2.2. could be implemented using 2 rangeQueries: 1 on `mingrade` and 1 on `maxgrade` combined with an `OR`

So an example 1 of filter facet could be (untested):

```
    {
        "facets": {
            "grade_6-8": {
                "filter": {
                    "or": [{
                        "range": {
                            "minGrade": {
                                "gte": 6,
                                "lte": 8
                            }
                        }
                    },
                    {
                        "range": {
                            "maxGrade": {
                                "gte": 6,
                                "lte": 8
                            }
                        }
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

**EDIT**: the above is a:

- facet called `grade_6-8`
- of type "filter facet"
- that contains a `or`- filter
- which in turn contains 2 [range filters](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-range-filter.html) . 1 for `minGrade` and 1 for `maxGrade`.
- **NOTE** You should repeat this for all the ranges you need separately

**EDIT 2**
when defining only 1 `Grade` per document instead of `minGrade` and `maxGrade` the solution changes. It becomes possible to do this with a simple rangequery. Something like:

```
    {
        "query": {
            "match_all": {}
        },
        "facets": {
            "grade_ranges": {
                "range": {
                    "field": "grade",
                    "ranges": [{
                        "to": 2
                    }, {
                        "from": 3,
                        "to": 5
                    }, {
                        "from": 6,
                        "to": 8
                    }, {
                        "from": 9,
                        "to": 12
                    }, {
                        "from": 13
                    }]
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

If this isn't what you're after please be more specific what you want.

Comment: Thanks, I think you get the gist of what I am asking. I want the user to be able to Click on the filter. So I want to display all possible Grade ranges. How in your above syntax, does it know which DB Field to use? I do not see... "field": "Grade"

Comment: Ehmm, firstoff, I now realize you said you changed your db to 1 column `grade`. I've given a solution for records with 2 columns `minGrade` and `maxGrade` as you mentioned earlier. See explanation in the answer at the bottom how this is constructed. **note**: this isn't a **range facet** which you still seem to be trying, since that can't be done with 2 fields afaik.

Comment: Please move your comment with code to your original question so it becomes readable and I may have a look how to do a range query on 1 field.